# Adjust the height of specific selectizeInput boxes in shiny

Tags: css, shiny

My app has many selectizeInput boxes.  To control the styles I use the following code:

```
tags$style(type='text/css', ".selectize-input { font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px;} .selectize-dropdown { font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px; }"),
```

This gets applied universally to all the selectize-input boxes.  How do I change the height of specific input box?. For example:

First Selectize-Input

```
tags$style(type='text/css', ".selectize-input { font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px;} .selectize-dropdown { font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px; }"),
                            div(style = "font-size: 11px;", selectizeInput(inputId = "demograph", label = "FILTER - I:",choices = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
                            options = list(maxItems = 1, placeholder = "All Parameters")))
```

Second Selectize-Input

```
tags$style(type='text/css', ".selectize-input { padding: 2px; min-height: 0;} .selectize-dropdown { line-height: 10px; }"),
                                div(style = "font-size: 11px;", selectizeInput(inputId = "demographFilt", label = "Choose a subset:",
                                choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE,options = list(placeholder = "All Parameters")))
```

How do I change the height of the second selectize input box?  If I change the `line-height` the change gets applied on both the boxes.  I tried the following:

```
tags$head(tags$style("#demographFilt{line-height:30px;}"))
```

but it doesn't help.

Comment: Are you doing your CSS only within the app or do you have a CSS sheet that you're loading as well?

Comment: @MJH I am not loading any CSS sheet, I am using the CSS functionality given within shiny.